# Wait for Future result, in another thread

Tags: java, concurrency

In following piece of code, the requirement is to publish a message to some UI thread, about results of a `Callable` running.

```
Future<T> aFuture = aExecutorService.submit(aCallable); //suppose in thread A

aExecutorService.execute(new Runnable() { //suppose in thread B
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        final T aresult = aFuture.get();
                        sendSuccessMesage(aResult);
                    }catch( . . . . . . e)
                      . . . . . . . 
                      sendExceptionHappenedMessage(e.getMessage());
                      . . . . . . .
                    }
                }
```

If ever the thread A is interrupted, will thread B keep waiting for result forever ?
What is the alternate/safe way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried to make a little prototype testing this?

Comment: Yep, My UI thread gets all messages in cases: success, callable thread interupted, future cancelled , Exception in callable, Exception in future and so. The thing I'm worried about is a forever waiting lost thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If task `aCallable` is cancelled, the get() might never return. The safest and most efficient way to do this is to use one task.

```
Future future = aExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final T aresult = aCallable.call();
            sendSuccessMesage(aResult);
        } catch(Throwable e)
            sendExceptionHappenedMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});

// to cancel.
future.cancel(true);
```

An alternative to cancelling it is to have an AtomicBoolean when you set to true and check for if cancelled. This way a `sendCancelledMessage` can still be sent if this is required.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this. OK, call runs in this thread and all messaging is also in this thread only. Now how do I cancel this thread and send a message about it ?

Comment: You can cancel as above.  If the `future.isDone()` is false it can mean nothing will happen (not even an error is passed)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you handle interruption in Thread A. For example:

```
Future<T> aFuture = null;
try {
    aFuture = aExecutorService.submit(aCallable);
    Thread.sleep(FOREVER);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    if (aFuture != null) {
        aFuture.cancel(true); //true = interrupts
    }
}
```

In that case, `aFuture.get()` in thread B will throw an InterruptedException too, which you can catch.

Comment: Yes I can do that but this might result in UI thread getting wrong messages. Thing is, I'm reporting _callable interruption_ and _future cancelling_ to my UI thread. (UI thread can cancel future any time it wants.)

Comment: @wingman in any case, `future.get()` will throw a `CancellationException` is the future gets cancelled.